# Linq Query for array of Objects

Tags: linq-to-objects

I have Array of objects SomeObjects[] objects. This 'objects' may contain type of 'Employee', 'Customer' or something else. I wanted to write a linq query if 'objects' contain type of 'Employee' and if his name (Employee.Name) is 'John', I want to get the employeeid.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use the safe cast operator `as` operator in your query to find objects of a specific type and have them cast to that type:

```
var employees = from obj in objects
                let emp = obj as Employee
                where emp != null && emp.Name == "John"
                select emp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`OfType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to filter objects based on their type, then use the [`Where` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) to filter on the name:

```
var query = objects.OfType<Employee>()
                   .Where(e => e.Name == "John")
                   .Select(e => e.EmployeeId);
```

This will return the employee IDs for all employees with the name of "John." If you expect only one person to match that criteria, you can replace the `Where` method with `Single`, or if you want to take the first result use `First`. However, if you expect one person but don't know whether they exist, you'll want to use `SingleOrDefault`:

```
Employee result = objects.OfType<Employee>()
                         .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Name == "John");
if (result != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.EmployeeId);
}
```